# Глюк симулятора, или нововведение?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Столкнулся с очень странной ситуацией, пишу обычно без автолояута, и под каждый  тип устройства создаю свои параметры, после обновление при изменение симулятора (5, 6, 6+) Симулятор показывает новые размеры и шрифты, хотя я ничего не менял, с чем это может быть связанно ??

[image: 5ка]

[image: 6ка]

Вот 2 девайса, 5ка и 6ка. Разницы не отличить...

Comment: а вы указываете шрифт, или используется системный?

Comment: Шрифты использовал кастомные, но дело не только в шрифтах, вьюхи тоже расширились.

Answer (score 0):

На вид вроде бы не изменилось ничего/ на plus - картинка скейлится если не добавить картинки в xcasset подходящие для iphone 6 plus launch image и appicon (HD 5.5")